# The images of the application are not loaded on some devices

Tags: android, eclipse, image, crash, device

I have a problem. It seems that on some devices, none of my images are loading, even the icons. On Galaxy S4 for example, it doesnt load anything. It doesnt crash, but the images are not loading.

Comment: Did you check if the S4 phone has the option not load images on? if it didn't load anywhere I'd say it's a permission issue but if it loads in some places it looks like a device misconfiguration to me.

Comment: are you loading images programmatically? if yes, could you please give your code here.

Comment: In my layout I have: android:background="@raw/bg1"